# iOS Swift: How to merge two shapes into a solid color shape using UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

[image]

Hey~~
I am trying to draw a solid round dot with a rectangle handle on top of it.
(backcolor: purple, forecolor: black)

However, the shapes are all correct, but when I am coloring it, there is a gap at the shape overlapping area, which cannot be filled with solid color.

How should I correct it? Thanks!

```
var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

func draw() {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    // draw a rectangle
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 100))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 100))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 0))

    // draw a circle
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    // fill colors with purple and black
    self.shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.shapeLayer?.fillColor = foreColor.cgColor
    self.backgroundColor = backColor
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw your rectangle in the opposite direction:

```
// draw a rectangle
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 100))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 100))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 0))
```

The [*non-zero winding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) fill used by CoreGraphics uses the direction of the lines to determine inside/outside.

---

Alternatively, you can reverse the direction of your circle:

```
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: 50,
    startAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides @vacawama 's answer, another approach I found out is that I can use a non-enclosed rectangle instead of a closed rectangle, the rect is opened in one side that was connecting with the circle:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    // an open rectangle
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 52))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 52))

    // the same circle
    path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)))
```

This works too, but it is really good to know about the "non-zero winding rule", so cool, thanks!

I am happy now :)